# Free action by cyclic group.

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group acting on a set $X$. If $g\in G$ has no fixed points, prove or disprove the cyclic group $\left \langle g  \right \rangle$ acts freely on $X$.

edit: Can also assume $g$ has finite order.

Comment: I've tried supposing $<g>_x$ is not the identity for some $x\in X$ and using that $<g>_x$ is is normal, but I get no where.

Comment: By hypothesis, you know that $g\cdot x\neq x$ for all $x\in X$. Does it follow that, say, $g^2\cdot x \neq x$ for all $x\in X$?

Comment: well no if $g$ has order 2.

Comment: What is the kernel of the homomorphism $G\rightarrow Sym(X)$. Can it intersect $\langle g\rangle$ nontrivially while not containing $g$?

Comment: I don't follow.

Answer (score 1):

You have edited your question to only talk about finite groups. So I will edit my hint, but keep the same flavour:

**Hint:** The action of a group $G$ on an object/set $X$ corresponds to a homomorphism $G\rightarrow\operatorname{Aut}(X)$. If this action is free then this map is injective (these are not equivalent conditions though). So, take a group $G$ which acts on an object $X$ where $|G|>|\operatorname{Aut}(X)|$...

In the previous version of the hint, I was suggesting taking $G$ to be infinite. This works for precisely the same reason, but is slightly easier to "see".

**Counter-examples:**

For a concrete counter-example in the infinite case, let $\mathbb{Z}$ act on a square by rotation. Then the element $1\in\mathbb{Z}$ acts without fixed points. What can you say about the action of the element $4\in\langle 1\rangle=\mathbb{Z}$?

This counter-example ports over to the finite case by picking some natural number $n$ such that $\mathbb{Z}_n$ acts non-trivially by rotations on the square, and such that $4\neq1\pmod n$. Why?

Comment: Sorry, I don't see the hint.

Comment: @user Sorry, I tried to edit this on my phone, but it didn't work. On my PC now. Basically, let $\mathbb{Z}$ act on a set such that $1\in\mathbb{Z}$ acts without fixed points...

Comment: the generator is supposed to be fixed point free, so I'm not sure yet how to get a counterexample as you are suggesting.

Comment: For example, let $\mathbb{Z}$ act on two points by swapping those points. The element $\langle 1\rangle$ acts without fixed points, but the action of $\mathbb{Z}$ is not free...

Comment: @user I have edited my answer. The same idea still works.

Comment: Sorry to edit my question mid answer. Still, I'm confused. "4" acts as the identity in your example, so it's fixing all points. I guess that shows your Z action is not free, but if the cyclic group is finite, I don't your example.

Comment: @user1729 The notation ${\rm Aut}(X)$ for a set $X$ is unusual. It would be preferable to write ${\rm Sym}(X)$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Sorry, I was thinking of $X$ as a square, so really meant to write "object" rather than "set". I've edited it to read "an object/set $X$", so now $\operatorname{Aut}(X)$ would be more usual (although please say if it is still unusual...!).

Answer (score 0):

Let $G$ be $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$, and $X=\{a,b\}$.
Let $G$ act on $X$ by $1\cdot a = b$ and $1\cdot b=a$ (the whole action is determined by that of $1$).
Hence $1$ has no fixpoint, although $2$ acts as the identity, i.e. $\langle 1\rangle$ doesn't act freely.